# Raising the vertical position of \chapter and \tableofcontents using amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents, positioning, titles, amsbook, vertical

I am required to have 1 inch margins all around my amsbook document and am having trouble figuring out how to reduce the vertical space at the top of each page containing a heading such as list of figures, table of contents, chapters.

My very inelegant first approach was to add 
\newgeometry{top=0.7cm, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in}
...
\restoregeometry

for each chapter heading. However, this doesn't work for my table of contents, which spills over onto two pages: it raises the text on the second page too high.

Can you recommend any solutions that wouldn't run into that issue? I have seen solutions for the book document class which redefine the \makechapter command, but I'm not sure how to do that for amsbook.

Thank you.

Here's what my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{flafter} %prevents floats from floating up the current page
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
    \chapter*{An unnumbered header}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \section{A numbered section header}
    \lipsum[2]
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header} 
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}
    \chapter{A numbered chapter header}



    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have seen solutions for the `book` document class which redefine the `\makechapter` command, but I'm not sure how to do that for `amsbook`.

Here's a set of instructions that you will let you achieve your formatting objectives while using the `amsbook` class:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{7.5pc}{3.75pc}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{7.5pc}{0pc}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Happy (La)TeXing!

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem entirely.